# Como armazenar conteúdo de Memo em variável string no Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Preciso armazenar o conteúdo do `Memo1` numa variável string, mas assim não funcionou:

```
sHTML := Memo1.Lines;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sHTML := Memo1.Text;
```

Assim irá funcionar, agora se você precisa de alguma coisa a mais, especifique na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente utilizo `Memo1.Lines.Text`

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser feito feito das seguintes 3 formas, pode criar dois `memos` e um `botão` no evento `onClick` do botão passa o seguinte código para ele:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
    AText: String;
begin
  Memo2.Lines.Add('Option 1');
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count -1 do AText := AText + Memo1.Lines[i];
  Memo2.Text := Memo2.Text + AText;
  Memo2.Lines.Add('--------------------------------------------');

  Memo2.Lines.Add('Option 2');
  AText := Memo1.Lines.Text;
  Memo2.Text := AText;
  Memo2.Lines.Add('--------------------------------------------');

  Memo2.Lines.Add('Option 3');
  AText := Memo1.Text;
  Memo2.Text := Memo2.Text + AText;
  Memo2.Lines.Add('--------------------------------------------');
end;
```

A segunda e terceira opção são praticamente iguais, no entanto a primeira vai pegar apenas o texto de cada linha o que pode ser interessante em certas ocasiões, agora vai tudo depender das suas necessidades.

Answer (score 0):

Se for variável -> `sHTML := Memo1.Text;`

Se for campo -> `sHTML.AsString := Memo1.Text;`